# Integers in Range have trailing decimal - how to remove?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a list like

```
{0,0.2x,0.4x,0.6x,0.8x,1}
```

If I try

```
Range[0, 1, 0.2] x
```

what I get is

```
{0., 0.2 x, 0.4 x, 0.6 x, 0.8 x, 1. x}
```

The main problem is the 1.x. How do I get that to just display as x? (And also to have the 0. display as 0?)

Comment: `Range[0, 1, 1/5] x`

Comment: @Artes thanks, that's helpful. Is there any way to get the non-integer fractions to display as decimals instead? The reason is that I'm using this for ticks on a plot, and decimals look nicer than fractions.

Comment: `Range[0, 1, 0.2] x /. {0. -> 0, 1. x -> x}`

Comment: `Range[0, 3, 0.2] x /. {x_ /; FractionalPart[x] == 0 -> IntegerPart[x]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Range[0, 1, 1/5] /. x_Rational :> N[x]) x
```

Gives:

```
{0, 0.2 x, 0.4 x, 0.6 x, 0.8 x, x}
```

This is more general since e.g.

```
(Range[0, 3, 1/5] /. x_Rational :> N[x]) x
```

Gives:

```
{0, 0.2 x, 0.4 x, 0.6 x, 0.8 x, x, 1.2 x, 1.4 x, 1.6 x, 1.8 x, 2 x, 
 2.2 x, 2.4 x, 2.6 x, 2.8 x, 3 x}
```